# error TS2307: Cannot find module './product'

Tags: angular, typescript

**app/product-detail.component.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './product'.**

I saw many answer but didn't worked for me. I am creating a demo app in angular 2 and facing this error. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.
my code is :

**Folder structure-**

```
app
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
    product.service.ts
    product.ts
    product-detail.component.ts
    main.ts
    mock-products.ts
node_modules ...
index.html
package.json
styles.css
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.json
```

**product.ts-**

```
  // product.ts
    export class product {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }
```

**product-detail.compenent.ts-**

```
//product-detail.compenent.ts

import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
@Component({
    selector:'my-product-detail',
    template: `
  <div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{product.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{product.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="product.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
})

export class ProductDetailComponent{
 @Input()
  product: Product;
}
```

**product.service.ts-**

```
\\product.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { product} from './product';
import { PRODUCTS} from './mock-products'

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
    getProducts():Promise<product[]>{
        return Promise.resolve(PRODUCTS);
    }
}
```

**mock-products.ts-**

```
//mock-products.ts

import { Product} from './product';

export const PRODUCTS: Product[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'product1' },
  { id: 12, name: 'product2' },
  { id: 13, name: 'product3' },
  { id: 14, name: 'product4' },
  { id: 15, name: 'product5' },
  { id: 16, name: 'product6' },
  { id: 17, name: 'product7' },
  { id: 18, name: 'product8' },
  { id: 19, name: 'product9' },
  { id: 20, name: 'product10' }
];
```

Comment: your product class name starts with 'p' not 'P'

Comment: But i am using   
 import { Product } from './product';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your product class name starts with 'p' not 'P'.
In your `product-detail.component.ts`

you have to import `product` not `Product` like in `product.service.ts`.
They are case sensitive.

Comment: it was by mistake: in product.service.ts. But the error is occuring in  product-detail.component.ts(2,22)

Comment: no..if your class name is 'product' you are importing correctly in `product.service.ts`

Comment: try changing the import in product.component or @PierreDuc solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of the class to start with a capital:

```
export class Product { //this one
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in **product-detail.compenent.ts**, You need to `import { product } from '@angular/core'` according to your folder structure.

You can do this

```
import { Product } from './product';   // if in the same directrory
```

or

```
import { Product } from '../product';  // if other directory but do accordingly.


import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';    // HERE
@Component({
    selector:'my-product-detail',
    template: `
  <div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{product.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{product.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="product.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
})
```